# What's the difference in "throw clothes away" and "throw away clothes"?

Tags: grammar, writing

Does it change the meaning of the sentence?

Are both  correct grammar?

In writing any kind of writing, which one is better to use?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  In particular, are you trying to make a sentence like "I will throw away your clothes" / "I will throw your clothes away"?  Or are you trying to use "throw-away" as an adjective  "These are throw-away clothes, so they aren't meant to last"?

Answer (score 2):

"Throw away" is a separable phrasal verb.  With a noun phrase (like "your clothes") both the separated and non-separated forms are possible

> I will throw away your clothes.

> I will throw your clothes away.

But with a pronoun, the phrase must be separated:

> I will throw them away.